# Is objectForKey slow for big NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, nsdictionary

1. Assume we have very big **NSDictionary**, when we want to call the **objectForKey** method, will it make lots of operations in core to get value? Or will it point to value in the memory directly?
2. How does it works in core?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The CFDictionary section of the [Collections Programming Topics for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/CFCollections.html) (which you should look into if you want to know more) states:

> A dictionary—an object of the CFDictionary type—is a hashing-based
>   collection whose keys for accessing its values are arbitrary,
>   program-defined pieces of data (or pointers to data). Although the key
>   is usually a string (or, in Core Foundation, a CFString object), it
>   can be anything that can fit into the size of a pointer—an integer, a
>   reference to a Core Foundation object, even a pointer to a data
>   structure (unlikely as that might be).

This is what wikipedia has to say about hash tables:

> Ideally, the hash function should map each possible key to a unique
>   slot index, but this ideal is rarely achievable in practice (unless
>   the hash keys are fixed; i.e. new entries are never added to the table
>   after it is created). Instead, most hash table designs assume that
>   hash collisions—different keys that map to the same hash value—will
>   occur and must be accommodated in some way. In a well-dimensioned hash
>   table, the average cost (number of instructions) for each lookup is
>   independent of the number of elements stored in the table. Many hash
>   table designs also allow arbitrary insertions and deletions of
>   key-value pairs, at constant average (indeed, amortized) cost per
>   operation.

The performance therefore depends on the quality of the hash. If it is good then accessing elements should be an O(1) operation (i.e. not dependent on the number of elements).

EDIT:

In fact after reading further the Collections Programming Topics for Core Foundation, apple gives an answer to your question:

> The access time for a value in a CFDictionary object is guaranteed to
>   be at worst O(log N) for any implementation, but is often O(1)
>   (constant time). Insertion or deletion operations are typically in
>   constant time as well, but are O(N*log N) in the worst cases. It is
>   faster to access values through a key than accessing them directly.
>   Dictionaries tend to use significantly more memory than an array with
>   the same number of values.

Comment: The fact that it shows either O(log N) or O(1) makes me wonder if they have a red black tree implementation, or if the log N accounts for duplicate chaining.

Comment: @JustinMeiners The worst case is for hash collisions

Comment: @JustinMeiners For future references, Core Foundation is open source. `CFDictionary` is implemented internally using a [`CFBasicHash`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFBasicHash.c).

Comment: @JustSid good to know. I was just thinking about how CFArray has multiple implementations for different purposes. and wondered if the same was true with the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

`NSDictionary` is essentially an Hash Table structure, thus Big-O for lookup is O(1). However, to avoid reallocations (and to achieve the O(1)) complexity you should use `dictionaryWithCapacity:` to create a new Dictionary with appropriate size with respect to the size of your dataset.

Comment: Using dictionaryWithCapacity will in the normal case provide minimal to no performance increase.  In fact the Apple docs say that it is only a hint. I have benchmarked with NSArray sizes between 10 and 10,000,000 and found no meaningful advantage.  The main disadvantage is the time and thinking spend on the calculation that is better spendt

Comment: You cannot guarantee there will not be collisions in the table regardless of table size.